# How do I select the first row in an R data frame that meets certain criteria?

Tags: r, select, dataframe

How do I select the first row of an R data frame that meets certain criteria?

Here is the context:

I have a data frame with five columns:

```
"pixel", "year","propvar", "component", "cumsum."
```

There are 1,225 combinations of `pixel` and `year`, because the data was computed from the annual time series of 49 geographic pixels for each of 25 study years. Within each pixel-year, I have computed `propvar`, the proportion of total variance explained by a given component of the fast Fourier transform for the time series of a given pixel-year. I then computed `cumsum`, which is the cumulative sum of `propvar` for each frequency component within a pixel-year. The `component` column just gives you an index for the Fourier series component (plus 1) from which `propvar` was calculated.

I want to determine the number of components required to explain greater than 99% of the variance. I figure one way to do this is to find the first row within each pixel-year where `cumsum` > 0.99, and create a data frame from it with three columns, `pixel`, `year`, and `numbercomps`, where `numbercomps` is the number of components required within a given pixel-year to explain greater than 99% of the variance. I do not know how to do this in R. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
# CREATE A REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE!
df <- data.frame(year = c("2001", "2003", "2001", "2003", "2003"),
                 pixel = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a"), 
                 cumsum = c(99, 99, 98, 99, 99),
                 numbercomps=1:5)
df
#   year pixel cumsum numbercomps
# 1 2001     a     99           1
# 2 2003     b     99           2 
# 3 2001     a     98           3
# 4 2003     b     99           4
# 5 2003     a     99           5

# EXTRACT THE SUBSET YOU'D LIKE.
res <- subset(df, cumsum>=99)
res <- subset(res, 
              subset = !duplicated(res[c("year", "pixel")]),
              select = c("pixel", "year", "numbercomps"))
#   pixel year numbercomps
# 1     a 2001           1
# 2     b 2003           2
# 5     a 2003           5
```

**EDIT** Also, for those interested in `data.table`, there is this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key="pixel, year")    
dt[cumsum>=99, .SD[1], by=key(dt)]
```

Comment: Holy crap. Now I know why you have racked up 2,157 points in only 43 days of StackOverflow membership. Thanks, man! I have this response in the StackOverflow folder of my email client. I will acknowledge you in whatever publications result from this assistance. I LOVE the duplicated function, BTW. It is like...exactly what I needed. (BTW, the publications would, of course, result from much more work than this particular issue, LOL.) Have a good night.

Comment: Cool.  Do send me a copy of whatever pub comes of the project (though no acknowlegement necessary of course)!

Comment: Will do! And I have checked your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra -- Right on. Thanks for bringing me back here, as that's gotta be one of the funnest comments I've seen in my time on SO. Made me smile then; makes me smile now. (And Brash -- don't forget to send me that publication/manuscript when you've got it!)

Comment: maybe send it to all of us, you've got me interested :)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien (and Paul Hiemstra) Fellas, we ended up not going with the Fourier transform in our final measurement model, but thanks for this again, Josh.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume df is the dataset from which we have to select the first row that meets the criteria.
This two-line code will give you the required row.

```
row_index <- which(<criteria>, arr.ind = TRUE)[1]

df_required <- df[row_index,]
```