# Extract the first, second and last row that meets a criterion

Tags: r

I would like to know how to extract the last row that follow a criterion. I have seen the solution for getting the first one by the function "duplicate" in the next link [How do I select the first row in an R data frame that meets certain criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145670/how-do-i-select-the-first-row-in-an-r-data-frame-that-meets-certain-criteria/30374603#30374603).

However is it possible to get the second or last row that meet a criterion?

I would like to make a loop for each `Class` (here I only put two) and select the first, second and last row that meet the criterion `Weight >= 10`. And if there is no row that meets the criterion to get a NA.

Finally I want to store the three values (first, second, and last row) in a list containing the values for each class.

```
   Class Weight
1      A     20
2      A     15
3      B     10
4      B     23
5      A     11
6      B     12
7      B     11
8      A     25
9      A      7
10     B      3
```

Comment: Do you realize that `Weight` are characters rather numbers, and that you have a `matrix` rather a `data.frame`?

Comment: Just a side note: to get (only) the last entry per group you can use `duplicated(... , fromLast = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry, weight are numbers in a dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data table can help with this.
This is an edit off of Davids comment to move it into the answers as his approach is the correct way to do this.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(db)
DT[Weight >= 10][, .SD[c(1, 2, .N)], by = Class]
```

As as faster alternative also from David look at

```
 indx <- DT[Weight >= 10][, .I[c(1, 2, .N)], by = Class]$V1 ; DT[indx]
```

Which creates the wanted index using .I and then subsets DT based on those rows.

Comment: You didn't specify any condition here and you should use `by` instead of doing this manually per each class. The correct solution is `dt[Weight >= 10][, Weight[c(1, 2, .N)], by = Class]`

Comment: But it only takes the information about the class and weight. If I have more columns the function won't showed the rest of the columns. I have done the proof.
Do you know how to keep the information of all columns if there were more?

Comment: Then Try `dt[Weight >= 10][, .SD[c(1, 2, .N)], by = Class]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I was premature with my answer as your right all criteria were not met. look at Davids last solution, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I have edited my answer to reflect your comment. If you want to post your answer I can upvote and delete mine.

Comment: That's fine, You could also maybe add `indx <- dt[Weight >= 10][, .I[c(1, 2, .N)], by = Class]$V1 ;  dt[indx]` as an alternative for a faster solution, as `.SD` is pretty slow.

Comment: @DavidArenburg For whatever reason when I think .I, I always think row by row operations and immediately think slow, but because the nature of how data.table indexing this is much more efficient than the subset created by .DS. I will definitely need to remember that one going forward. Added to the the answer.

Comment: `.I` is a mystery to me to. I never understood why `dt[, .I, by = Class]` won't return indexes per group, for example.